# Trying clasp run <myfunction> (ENOENT) Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory /path/myproject/.clasprc.json

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, google-oauth, clasp

I am trying to run a function of a simple `GAS` project I have created such as.

```
$ mkdir myproject
$ cd myproject
$ clasp create --title "myproject"
$ vim Code.gs
## content of ./Code.gs
function main () {
  Logger.log("Hello World");
}
##
$ clasp push
$ clasp open
```

It works running it through the browser, but following the documentation of `clasp` I think I can

```
clasp help run
  run [options] [functionName]                Run a function in your Apps Scripts project
          --nondev                    Run script function in non-devMode
          -p, --params [StringArray]  Add parameters required for the function as a JSON String Array
```

So I do

```
$ clasp run main
```

And I get the following

```
(ENOENT) Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/path/to/myproject/.clasprc.json'
```

But so far I know I have such as file in `~/.clasprc.json` so I proceed copying it to my project's folders

```
$ cp ~/.clasprc.json ./
$ clasp run main
```

Now I get the following output

```
⠋ Running function: main(node:25561) ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Hey! It looks like you aren't authenticated for the scopes required by this script.
Please enter the scopes by doing the following:
1. Open Your Script: https://script.google.com/d/myscriptId/edit
2. File > Project Properties > Scopes
3. Copy/Paste the list of scopes here:
            ~ Example ~
https://mail.google.com/
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations
----(When you're done, press <Enter> 2x)----
```

So I check in myproject and I see I have no Scopes authenticated , so I decide to press `<Enter>`

```
Added 0 scopes to your appsscript.json' oauthScopes
Please `clasp login --creds <file>` to log in with these new scopes.
```

Currently I don't know where I am at so I do

```
$ clasp run main
```

To get the same previous output.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am actually seeing that the topic is quite more complex to analize, there are a lot of requirements to be done in order to run a script, the step by step process can be found here [clasp run howto](https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/docs/run.md)

Comment: you should answer yourself with this, I missed the comment first and the doc is what I was looking for, doing exactly what you post was describing